# Admin previliges for python, django , sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am new to python and begginer.

Is it necessary to have admin permissions for installing and working with Python , Django , Sqlite.. I have got all the softwares installed bt dont think i have admin previliges . While i am using command

```
syncdb
```

I am getting the result as 0 fixtures. But i am not able to create db with the above piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

Being `admin` or not has no effect at `syncdb` stage.

Is your DB already there? if yes, then changes in django `models` doesn't support migrations out of the box. So for example, if you have created DB and then changed your `models.py`running `syncdb` now will not change your model.

There is a pluggable app for Django that does exactly that though, and it works great. It's called [South](http://south.aeracode.org).

Comment: my doubt is do we need admin permission for python and django

Comment: @PavanK If you have python installed already, admin permission is not required

Comment: @Pramod thanks buddy. One more doubt is that i fear my python files are corrupted , because earlier there used to be icon of python on every .py file bt now the icons are suddenly disabled....

Comment: Maybe you mistakenly uninstalled a python ide which was associated with opening .py files? Don't think files are corrupted in this case.

Comment: @Pramod When i type python in command prompt , it is not being recognised i mean its corrupted rit??

Comment: Which os are you on? If Windows, try adding python to your PATH environment variable. On linux and mac python is installed by default